# Extent Report not getting generated for scenario outline in cucumber

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, extentreports, scenarios

I have facing an issue that in cucumber for scenario outline I am not able to generate the extent report but for scenario I don't have any problem for extent report.

I am sharing my test testrunner and pom.xml
Testrunner.java

```
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
        glue = {"com.test.stepdefinitions"},
        plugin = {"json:target/cucumber.json" , "html:target/site/cucumber-pretty"},
        tags ={"@tt"}

        )
pom.xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>  <!-- 2.5.0 -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
                </dependency>
```

please let me know if I am missing any dependency for report which is generating for scenario outline

Comment: I dont see dependency added for extentreport. Try using https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports

Comment: Considering all other configurations and setups are done correctly.

Comment: Hi Abhinav i added the dependency what you said,but still i am not able to generate report for "Scenario Outline" in "cucumber"

<dependency>
   <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
   <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Are yous sure that all other configurations have been done correctly? Seems there is some piece of configuration which is missing.

Comment: Hi abhinav i think all the configuration is done and it is generating report for scenario but its not generating report for "Scenario Outline".